# How does the community decide to put questions on hold? What is the criteria?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

1. [Question 1 (10k only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706271/tensor-conversion-requested-dtype-int32-for-tensor-with-dtype-float32)

[image]

2. [Question 2 (10k only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51797829/how-do-i-test-accuracy-in-tensorflow-and-is-this-program-working?noredirect=1#comment90553838_51797829)

[image]

The first one has been flagged a few days back. But even though its quality is lower than that of the second question it is still not reviewed. Does it have anything to do with the queue management or subjectivity?

I think Question 2 is more properly phrased, but it has been put on hold within a few hours. Should this question be considered a violation of the rules?

I have recently been allowed to access queues. So I am trying to understand this process better.

Comment: The close review queue is always very large (over 7k questions at the moment). It can take a long time for a question to be reviewed. Some questions get closed quickly because people see them when they are first posted so they don't have to wait for review.

Comment: Both questions are pretty bad. But there aren't as many curators around the [tag:tensorflow] tag as we would wish for a quick resolution.

Comment: As usual, the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) is the place to go...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is actually a useful resource in this particular instance.  It describes not only what questions are on topic here, but also which questions are *off* topic.

Notably, both questions suffer from this particular issue:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

For Question #1, the only thing we have to go off of is an image.  Images aren't useful to us since they don't allow any prospective answerer the ability to copy and paste the problem into their own environment and make an attempt at a solution.  What's *worse*, the image only contains a stack trace.  No code for us to go off of?  No way that we can answer the question.

For Question #2, there's an equally similar problem.  The asker posted only their code and asked if it was working.  Well...we can't debug code without data, so their question was *both* looking for debugging help (since they were unsure if it was working or not) *and* horribly broad, since "working" was ill defined by the OP.

Comment: So even though the comments may have more information if the question is not self-contained then it doesn't qualify. Right ?

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan The comments are important but they are not the main thing, the content of your question is important since the comments could be eliminated for various reasons, so a good question should have a good title and a good content, the comments will serve you so that go perfecting your question, and us to help you in it.